# How to dynamically generate an input field when checkboxes are checked

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

How can I generate a text field on every checked box. My checkbox field is also dynamic.

Here is my code:

```html
<div>
  <label> Products </label>
  <li ng-repeat="item in INDproducttypes">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="indProducts['item.value']" />
  </li>
</div>

<div>
  <div ng-show="indProducts==true">
    <input type="text" name="name">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should not use template markup in binding expressions. Change ng-model expression to "indProducts[item.value]".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we check the checkbox, the input field is shown, otherwise it is hidden:

```html
<div ng-app="DataEntryApp" ng-controller="DataEntryController">

  <div>
    <label> Products </label>
    <li ng-repeat="item in INDproducttypes">
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.value" />
    </li>
  </div>

  <div ng-repeat="item in INDproducttypes">
    <div ng-show="item.value">
      <input type="text" name="name">
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

**[CodePen](http://codepen.io/vkvicky-vasudev/pen/BLLNwZ)**

Comment: Thank you @vicky kumar. But i want to functionality like this.
when user click on check box the input field will show.
http://codepen.io/Akhil_dev/pen/VKKKNz

Comment: i  want separate input field for consumer and business check box click.

Comment: @Akhilendrayadav Can you further elaborate your second comment :i want separate input field for consumer and business check box click